# VirtualBox shared folder write permission - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, shared-folders, write-protect

I'm using the following command to mount my folder in VirtualBox:

```
sudo \mount -t vboxsf -o rw -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 Dropbox ~/Dropbox/
```

However, the folder is read-only. I re-installed Guest additions, and made sure the folder is not set as read-only in VirtualBox.

What's the right command to gain write permissions?

Comment: Got it! The right command is:

    sudo mount -t vboxsf -o rw -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o dmode=755 -o fmode=755 Dropbox ~/Dropbox/

Thanks for who tried to help :)

Answer (score 5):

The right command is:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmode=755,fmode=644 Dropbox ~/Dropbox/
```

Notice the fmode.